# iOS draw line in Scatter Graph Using Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

Add line in Scatter Graph. Below is normal code for draw the Scatter Graph using iOS Chart Framework.

```
        let xAxisValue: [Double] = [21.7,22.2,22.5,22.6,22.7,22.8,22.8,22.7,22.6,22.3,22.0,22.0,21.6,21.1,20.5,20.0,19.7,19.2,18.8,18.1,17.8,16.8,16.8,16.5,16.0,15.5,15.5,15.0,13.7,13.0,12.2,12.1,11.1,10.7,9.4,9.1,8.7,7.6,7.2,6.1,4.7,4.3,3.9,3.5,3.0,2.7,2.3,1.9,1.6,1.6,1.6,2.3,1.9,1.9,3.0,4.6,5.7,6.4,6.8,6.8,7.0,7.1,7.1,7.1,7.1,7.6,9.1,10.7,12.2,13.7,21.7]
    let yAxisValue: [Double] = [-1.1,-0.7,-0.1,0.0,1.5,3.0,4.6,6.1,7.6,9.1,10.7,10.7,12.2,13.7,15.2,16.2,16.8,17.7,18.3,19.4,19.8,21.0,21.0,21.3,21.8,22.3,22.4,22.9,23.9,24.4,25.0,25.1,25.7,25.9,26.5,26.6,26.8,27.2,27.4,27.4,27.4,25.9,24.4,22.9,21.1,19.8,18.3,16.8,15.5,15.2,14.4,13.9,12.2,11.1,10.5,9.2,7.6,6.1,4.6,3.4,3.0,2.3,1.5,1.2,0.1,0.0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.4,-0.6,-1.1]

    let yVals1 = (0..<xAxisValue.count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
        return ChartDataEntry(x: yAxisValue[i], y: xAxisValue[i])
    }
    
    let set1 = ScatterChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: "DS 1")
    set1.setScatterShape(.chevronUp)
    set1.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[0])
    set1.scatterShapeSize = 8

    let data: ScatterChartData = [set1]
    data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 7, weight: .light))

    chartView.data = data
```

Can't figure out how to draw line in scatter graph. Some suggestion is use **ScatterChartRenderer** class but not understand where to use that class. Expecting such type of result.
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7EgE.png)